# How to change the material of 1 or more faces of a object

Tags: materials

I would like to change the material of two faces of a cube to be glass as opposed to changing the entire cube to be made from glass. Is this possible to achieve or does each object have to be wholly comprised of 1 material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add all the materials you want for the object to the materials list. Then, in edit mode, select the faces you want for a specific material. With the faces selected, click on the material you want to use and then click “assign”.